# Android - Find the index of ListView item by text

Tags: java, android

I have two lists of Strings. One contains the items of a ListView and the other one contains some items from the first list.

Let me show you:
This is basically my ListView, we'll call it `Ore`:

```
<string-array name="ore">
        <item>10:00 - 11:00</item>
        <item>11:00 - 12:00</item>
        <item>12:00 - 13:00</item>
        <item>13:00 - 14:00</item>
        <item>14:00 - 15:00</item>
        <item>15:00 - 16:00</item>
        <item>16:00 - 17:00</item>
        <item>17:00 - 18:00</item>
        <item>18:00 - 19:00</item>
        <item>19:00 - 20:00</item>
        <item>20:00 - 21:00</item>
        <item>21:00 - 22:00</item>
    </string-array>
```

This is my first list (it's from my `strings.xml` but I've managed to turn it to a list of String).

The second list, we'll call it `CheckOre`:

```
12:00 - 13:00, 19:00 - 20:00, 15:00 - 16:00
```

```
for(String ora : CheckOre){
      for(String stringOra: Ore){
           if(ora.equals(stringOra)){
               // i want to get the index of ListView item by the text from Ore
          }
      }
}
```

As it says in the `if` condition, I want to get the index of a ListView item by text.
For example, if `ora` is `14:00 - 15:00`, I want to get the index, which is `4`.

Is there a method to help me do that? Thanks!

Comment: if you're going to use a for loop without an index, then obviously you wont have that available to you. so create your own counter variable which you increment, or you can use a for loop with an index, or even find a method to just find the index of the item in the list directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will return all same indexes in a **ArrayList** of integers:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getSameIndexes(ArrayList<String> arr1, ArrayList<String> arr2) {
     ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     for(int x = 0; x < arr1.size(); x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < arr2.size(); y++) {
           if(arr1.get(x).equals(arr2.get(y)))
               indexes.add(y);
         }
     }
     return indexes;
}
```

Just call it with `getSameIndexes(CheckOre, Ore);`

Alternatively you can use:

```
public int getIndex(ArrayList<String> arr1, ArrayList<String> arr2) {
     for(int x = 0; x < arr1.size(); x++) {
          for (int y = 0; y < arr2.size(); y++) {
               if (arr1.get(x).equals(arr2.get(y)))
                    return y;
          }
     }
     return -1;
}
```

Which will return the first element where items match when calling `getIndex(CheckOre, Ore);`

Comment: i don't know who downvoted you but this works as it should. it solved my problem and i thank you very much!!! I've tried by using switch but it's a lot of code and your solution is perfect! Thank you!!!

Comment: Use nested for loops? Is indexOf() a better choice?@Marius-Marian Burlacu

Answer (score 0):

You can use tag in the getView() like below,

```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      String test = getItem(position);
      convertView.setTag(test);
  }
```

I have tried in RecyclerView not in ListView but it should work. Also I will say the best way is as the [a_local_nobody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4729721/a-local-nobody) says.

Answer (score -1):

Use indexOf method

Kotlin language

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val listOre = listOf(
        "10:00 - 11:00",
        "11:00 - 12:00",
        "12:00 - 13:00",
        "13:00 - 14:00",
        "14:00 - 15:00",
        "15:00 - 16:00",
        "16:00 - 17:00",
        "17:00 - 18:00",
        "18:00 - 19:00",
        "19:00 - 20:00",
        "20:00 - 21:00",
        "21:00 - 22:00",
    )

    val checkOre = listOf(
        "12:00 - 13:00", "19:00 - 20:00", "15:00 - 16:00"
    )

    for (i in checkOre) {
        println(listOre.indexOf(i))
    }
}
```

The result:

```
2
9
5
```